# How to check/uncheck checkbox slowly kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my application, I'm using the kendo grid to display data. I'm using dropdown which contains three values called 'opt-in, opt-out and all'. when user select Opt-in from the drop-down and particular data is listing.

[image]

In the above grid, you can see, there is a checkbox column called **opt in**. once the user unchecks the checkbox that row is quickly removing from the grid. (because of its become to the opted-in status ).

code (this works fine)

```
$("#productServicesByLocationGrid .k-grid-content").on("change", "input.chkbx", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var grid = $("#productServicesByLocationGrid").getKendoGrid();
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    dataItem.set("OptIn", this.checked);
});
```

I need to avoid this quick remove and need to add some slowness to uncheck the checkbox. therefor, I change my code as follows,

```
$("#productServicesByLocationGrid .k-grid-content").on("change", "input.chkbx", function (e) {

    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second
    setTimeout(function () {
    e.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#productServicesByLocationGrid").getKendoGrid();
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        dataItem.set("OptIn", this.checked);
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
});
```

But after changing the code as above, it's not working fine, the **checkbox is unchecking slowly, it's working**, but it's opt-in status not changed to the opt-out status. **how can I add some slowness to the checkbox to display slowly uncheck and check state change?** have any proper way to show slowly checkbox uncheck and check.

Comment: If the checkbox is, anyhow, bound to the data and when user unchecks it, it changes the data automatically, then with timeout you'll need to do that manually, I think.

Comment: What is `this` and `this.checked` in the new anonymous function? I'd try saving `this.checked` to a local const before `setTimeout`. 
The `e.preventDefault();` after the timeout worries me too.

Comment: Is the delay for a visual effect only, or is the 1 second a time period in which the user can 're-opt-in` the unchecked opt-in ?